# How can I force my Navmesh agent to only move four directions? (for 2D)

Tags: unity, 2d, movement, navmesh

I'm making a 2D game in Unity. For 2D I am using the NavmeshSurface2D-plus master package available on github. My enemy object is chasing my main character nicely, it's ok. I set my main character to only move in four directions (with Vector2.left, right, up, down). Likewise, how do I move my enemy object with the "Nav Mesh Agent" component?

If I didn't use "NavMeshAgent", I could only make my enemy object move up, down, left, right under certain conditions. But at that time, since I wasn't using NavMesh, my enemy object would be stuck on the walls.

---

EDIT:
As an example, the image below shows the path followed by the turquoise enemy character to the yellow main character. (agent.SetDestination(target.position);)
I examined the corners of this path by assigning them to a Vector3 list with "agent.path.corners", but I guess it is not possible to make any changes on them.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSWvv.jpg

The image below is the route I want it to be. (yellow line) I can't do this using "NavMeshagent", I thought to learn path and corner coordinates and set them manually, but this is not a general solution.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn3zl.jpg

Corner information of the path followed by the navmesh agent as below:

```
List<Vector3> corner= new List<Vector3>();

public void PathMove(NavMeshPath path)
{
    Vector3 previousCorner = path.corners[0];
    corner.Add(previousCorner);
    int i = 1;
    while (i < path.corners.Length)
    {
        Vector3 currentCorner = path.corners[i];
        previousCorner = currentCorner;
        corner.Add(previousCorner);
        i++;
    }
    foreach (Vector3 item in corner)
    {
        Debug.Log(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: You can query `NavMeshAgent.path` to read the current path, decide whether to move vertically or horizontally based on the next segment of that path, then move it manually, no? `NavMeshAgent.isStopped` will let you park the agent so it doesn't do any automatic diagonal movement of its own.

Comment: I thought about your suggestion and edited my question.